# How to compile rust code as PIC binary since rustc don't have '-fPIC' flag?

Tags: rust

I tried to compile some rust code but rustc print out this error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32S cannot be used against local symbol; recompile with -fPIC
```

But rustc don't have '-fPIC' flag so how can I compile PIC binary with rustc?

I tried '-C relocation-model=pic -C code-model=large' but still get this error.

**EDIT:**

I figured out the error! I use some assembly code in asm! macro and it use some address of outside symbol, that why rust try to use 'R_X86_64_32S' and since the binary is linked to 0xffff800000000000, it cause the error.

**EDIT2:**

This is the code that cause similar error:

```
#![feature(asm)]
fn main () 
{
    unsafe
    {
        asm! ("lea rax, [label]
              label:"
              :
              :
              :
              : "intel");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
= note: /usr/bin/ld: main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.0.rcgu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text._ZN4main4main17h9e0ea2b04575dfdbE' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

Comment: Rust [builds and links as position independent by default](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/16340). Something else is probably happening. How did you get that error - can you give a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I'm messing with bare metal code so it will be impossible to build unless you have cross-compiled core crate

Comment: You should post the asm! code that caused the error in the question, then post your edit as an answer, maybe with a little more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors can be fixed this way:

Fixed code:

```
#![feature(asm)]
fn main () 
{
    unsafe
    {
        asm! ("call label
              label:
              pop rax"
              :
              :
              :
              : "intel");
    }
}
```

The point is: you can't load a label address directly, but you must use a call to push that address into stack, then pop the address.